# vmware fusion 6 too slow on mavericks

Tags: memory, windows-7, vmware, osx-mavericks, vmware-fusion

I'm using windows 7 on vmware fusion 6 on mavericks. its super slow. i had no problems when i was using it on osx lion but since i have updated to mavericks its super slow. in activity monitor memory given to vmware is about 20 mb and i dont understand why is that. following are the images which might explain my problem. can someone help me out?

1-http://i42.tinypic.com/v2y9na.png
2-http://i43.tinypic.com/2v2zlgi.png

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do this, turn off app nap....

https://communities.vmware.com/message/2312094#2312094

Comment: it havent resolved the issue fully but its improved. i guess i'm having the issue because i'm running 64bit version windows on vm.